# How do I get a substitute row after left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, left-join

I have to construct a view from 2 tables: **languages** and **articles**

Table **Language**:

```
langId:1   langCode:en   priority: 1
langId:2   langCode:da   priority: 2 
langId:3   langCode:es   priority: 3
```

Table **Article**:

```
langId: 1, articleId: 1 title: "First art-en"   originId: "ASDF"
langId: 2, articleId: 2 title: "First art-da"   originId: "ASDF"
langId: 1, articleId: 3 title: "Second art-es"  originId: "AAAA"
```

Same article in different languages will have a unique `OriginId`.
I need to pick a substitute row when the article is not present for a particular language and that should be based on the language priority.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?
I want to avoid using CTE/Temp tables and Looping statements.

Comment: Does avoiding CTE means avoiding derived tables?

Comment: I m fine with sub-queries  but do not want to create any temporary tables/ common table entities..etc. This is for a view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a prioritization query.  You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select al.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by l.priority) as seqnum                                
      from article a join
           language l
           on a.langid = l.langid
     ) al
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. But then... this solves only half the problem. You are getting the row with least priority.. but then, it should "Substitute" row after left/ right outer join. How can I do that?